# MouseEvent "GetX" & "GetY" Returning Alternating Values

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX `Label` that's created & added inside of a `TitledPane`. I want that `Label` to be draggable, and return to it's original position after I stop dragging it.

The label is created & inserted into the `TitledPane` by the following Java code:

```
Label label = new Label("Label");
NodeMakeDraggable(label, label.getText());
myPane.getChildren().add(label);
```

Where `myPane` is the `TitledPane` object, and `MakeNodeDraggable` is the following function:

```
public void NodeMakeDraggable(Node node, String id)
{
    node.setId(id);
    node.toFront();
    
    Double originalPosX = node.getTranslateX();
    Double originalPosY = node.getTranslateY();
    
    node.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) 
        {
            node.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
            
            System.out.println("Pressed!");
        }
    });
    
    node.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) 
        {
            node.setTranslateX(originalPosX);
            node.setTranslateY(originalPosY);
            node.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
            
            System.out.println("Released!");
        }
    });
        
    node.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) 
        {
            node.setTranslateX(event.getX());
            node.setTranslateY(event.getY());
            
            System.out.println("Dragged! (" + event.getX() + ", " + event.getY() +")");
        }
    });
        
    node.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) 
      {
            if (!event.isPrimaryButtonDown())
                node.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
            
            System.out.println("Entered!");
        }
    });
        
    node.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) 
        {
            if (!event.isPrimaryButtonDown())
                node.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
            
            System.out.println("Exited!");
        }
    });
}
```

While this code does make the `Label` draggable, unfortunately there appears to be an issue.

Whenever I attempt to drag the `Label`, the outputs recieved from the `getX` and `getY` class functions of the `MouseEvent` class appear to provide alternating readings every time I read from them. The resultant dragging looks like this:

[image]

Taking a look at the printed output from the `getX` and `getY` functions that I get in the overriden callback function `setOnMouseDragged`, I see the following values in the output console:

```
Entered!
Pressed!
Dragged! (11.999999999999998, 9.399999999999993)
Dragged! (0.8000000000000007, 0.0)
Dragged! (11.999999999999998, 10.200000000000005)
Dragged! (0.8000000000000007, 0.799999999999983)
Dragged! (12.799999999999999, 11.000000000000016)
Dragged! (0.8000000000000007, 1.5999999999999943)
Dragged! (13.6, 11.799999999999999)
Dragged! (0.8000000000000007, 2.4000000000000057)
Dragged! (14.4, 11.799999999999999)
Dragged! (0.8000000000000007, 3.1999999999999886)
Dragged! (15.199999999999998, 12.60000000000001)
Dragged! (0.8000000000000007, 4.0)
Dragged! (15.999999999999998, 12.60000000000001)
Dragged! (0.8000000000000007, 4.799999999999983)
Dragged! (15.999999999999998, 13.400000000000022)
Dragged! (1.6000000000000014, 4.799999999999983)
Dragged! (15.999999999999998, 14.200000000000005)
Dragged! (1.6000000000000014, 5.599999999999994)
Dragged! (16.799999999999997, 14.200000000000005)
Dragged! (1.6000000000000014, 6.400000000000006)
Dragged! (17.6, 14.200000000000003)
Dragged! (1.5999999999999979, 7.199999999999989)
Dragged! (17.6, 15.000000000000014)
Dragged! (2.399999999999995, 7.199999999999989)
Dragged! (17.6, 15.799999999999997)
Dragged! (2.399999999999995, 8.0)
```

It can be seen that there appear to be two sets of position values that alternate whenever the current position of the mouse gets queried.

Why is this happening? Could the fact that the `Label` I'm dragging is placed within the `TitledPane` causing some sort of interference with the position of the mouse?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: `#setTranslateX` sets up the amount to move the element on the next render, but you're continually feeding it the original node's position (as an offset, mind you). So it will continually want to "jump" that little bit of the original position. Perhaps you meant to set the actual position. or do a calculation of that position minus the previous coordinates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things to know in order to understand why you are getting the behavior you're getting:

1. `MouseEvent.getX()` and `MouseEvent.getY()` give you the coordinates of the mouse event (i.e. the coordinates of the position of the mouse) *in the coordinate system of the source of the event* (i.e. the `Label`). So `getX()` and `getY()` will be relative to the current position of the `Label`.
2. `translateX` and `translateY` are *properties* (so setting them will just change their value, and replace any previous value) which determine the amount the `Label` is moved from its layout position (essentially its original position).

When you do

```
node.setTranslateX(event.getX());
node.setTranslateY(event.getY());
```

you will move the node so its origin (top left) is at the same position as the mouse. If you could evaluate `getX()` and `getY()` for a new mouse event immediately after this, you would necessarily get `0` for both (because you have moved the node so its origin is where the mouse is).

To make this concrete, suppose the user clicks on the label at a position that is 11 pixels right and 8 pixels down from the top left of the label, and drags at a speed such that the mouse has moved one pixel right and one pixel down each time a drag event is detected. (This setup gives behavior similar to the values you see.)

This means the first drag event will occur with `getX()` returning `12` and `getY()` returning `9`. So you call

```
node.setTranslateX(12);
node.setTranslateY(9);
```

which, as described above, moves the node so its top left is at the mouse cursor. (So now the mouse is at `(0,0)` relative to the node.)

The next drag event occurs after the mouse has moved right one pixel and down one pixel, so on that drag event `getX()` and `getY()` both return `1`. So now you call

```
node.setTranslateX(1);
node.setTranslateY(1);
```

which moves the node back almost to its original position (just moved by one pixel right and down). If you could evaluate the position of the mouse relative to the node after this translation, you would get `(12,9)`: the mouse started at `(11,8)`, has moved two pixels right and down, and the node is moved one pixel right and down.

On the third drag event, the mouse moves a further pixel right and down, so `getX()` returns `13` and `getY()` returns `10`. You then call

```
node.setTranslateX(13);
node.setTranslateY(10);
```

which again moves the origin of the node to the position of the mouse. So on the next drag event, the mouse has moved one pixel right and down relative to the node, and so `getX()` and `getY()` both return `1` again, so you move the node back almost to its original position.

And so it continues. Notice how you are alternately moving the node to under the mouse and moving it back close to its original position, creating the flickering you see, and creating the alternating values in your log.

[User vv provides one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77081071/2189127) where you keep track of the coordinates of the node relative to the scene, which works. That isn't really necessary though; here is another solution.

The key point is that if you are dragging a node smoothly, the mouse will always remain in the same position relative to the node. Then the idea is to record where the mouse is originally pressed, and when the mouse is dragged move the node so that the mouse is back in the same relative position.

So the strategy is:

1. Record the coordinates of the mouse relative to the node when the mouse is pressed.
2. On a mouse drag, measure how far the mouse has moved relative to its pressed coordinates.
3. Update the `translateX` and `translateY` coordinates by adding those differences to them. This will move the node so the mouse remains at the same relative coordinates.

In the example described above, we would record on the mouse click that it occurred at `(11,8)`. The first mouse drag gives coordinates of `(12,9)`. We want to move the node so that the mouse is again at `(11,8)`, so we *increase* `translateX` by `12 - 11 = 1` and *increase* `translateY` by `9 - 8 = 1`:

```
double deltaX = event.getX() - mouseDownLocation.x;
node.setTranslateX(node.getTranslateX() + deltaX);

double deltaY = event.getY() - mouseDownLocation.y;
node.setTranslateY(node.getTranslateY() + deltaY);
```

Here is an implementation and example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Label label = new Label("Label");
        label.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        label.setBackground(Background.fill(Color.LIMEGREEN));
        root.getChildren().add(label);

        makeNodeDraggable(label);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void makeNodeDraggable(Node node) {
        var mouseDownLocation = new Object() { double x, y; };
        
        double originalTranslateX = node.getTranslateX();
        double originalTranslateY = node.getTranslateY();

        node.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            mouseDownLocation.x = e.getX();
            mouseDownLocation.y = e.getY();
        });

        node.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            double deltaX = e.getX() - mouseDownLocation.x;
            node.setTranslateX(node.getTranslateX() + deltaX);
            double deltaY = e.getY() - mouseDownLocation.y;
            node.setTranslateY(node.getTranslateY() + deltaY);
        });

        // return to original position on release:
        node.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
            node.setTranslateX(originalTranslateX);
            node.setTranslateY(originalTranslateY);
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a scene-relative mouse coordinate then adjust the translation base on the mouse delta.

Why you get that kind of behavior is because on how the event **getX()** and **getY()** values are being used. Those values are the origin of the source node of the **MouseEvent** not in the scene.

try doing like this. see if this helps.

```
public void NodeMakeDraggable(Node node, String id)
{
    node.setId(id);
    node.toFront();

    final Delta dragDelta = new Delta(); //delta class
    
    node.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) 
        {
            dragDelta.x = node.getTranslateX() - event.getSceneX();
            dragDelta.y = node.getTranslateY() - event.getSceneY();
            node.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
        }
    });

    node.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) 
        {
            node.setTranslateX(dragDelta.x + event.getSceneX());
            node.setTranslateY(dragDelta.y + event.getSceneY());
            node.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        }
    });

    node.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) 
        {
            node.setTranslateX(dragDelta.x + event.getSceneX());
            node.setTranslateY(dragDelta.y + event.getSceneY());
        }
    });
}

// hold x and y values
private class Delta { double x, y; }
```